# Notifying on all completed schedules with sprring

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have a Java, Spring application where I schedule some report jobs. The component looks like this:

```
@Component
public class RegisterReportSchedules implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ts;

    private List<String> reportSchedules; //contains list of report schedules

    @Autowired
    private SomeTask sometask;


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {

                reportSchedules.forEach((String schedule) -> {
                    ReportSchedule reportSchedule = new ReportSchedule(schedule,
                            propertiesUtil.getProperty(schedule + "." + Constants.CRON));

                        ts.schedule(new ReportTask(reportSchedule),
                                new CronTrigger(reportSchedule.getCronExpression()));
                    });

        }


        class ReportTask implements Runnable {

        private ReportSchedule schedule;

        public ReportTask(ReportSchedule schedule) {
            this.schedule = schedule;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sometask.process(schedule);
        }
    }

}
```

Say I have 5 `reportSchedules` to process. After all 5 `ReportTasks` have been completed, I need to write into a db table one entry to say all report task completed.

But how can I track this information about each report schedule is completed in my application?

Do I need to write to database table for each schedule completed or is there a better alternative within `Spring` that will trigger a notification event of some sort which I can then use to write the `ALL COMPLETED` event to the table? Appreciate if some answers with examples are given.

Comment: Do you need to track the `reportSchedule` (`String`s) _after_ they've been processed?

Comment: @user2478398 - nope

Comment: @M06H, i don't think there is built in event by `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, so all you can do is keep an counter variable and at the start of `run()` increment it and at last `decrement` it. Check if it's 0 and do DB entry if condition satisfies.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to track the `reportSchedules`, I'd be tempted to do something like:

- Move to use a `Queue` so that the `String`s are removed when you `poll`.
- Track the number of tasks that you submit. (*)
- Add a custom `ApplicationEvent` type of `ReportScheduleProcessedEvent` (or similar) and publish one of these (to Spring's `ApplicationEventPublisher`) at the end of the `ReportTask`'s `run` method.
- Add a new `ApplicationListener` for this type, which waits until it has received as many events as you tracked in (*); and then publishes something to the database.

I'm afraid I haven't provided any code here, since you might or might not need to care about thread-safety at a bunch of points above, and handling this appropriately might not be trivial.

---

Edit; per comment asking for a sample.  I'll assume you're using at least spring 4.3.

Edit Edit: per more comments.

```
abstract class ReportScheduleEvent extends ApplicationEvent { ... }

public class IncomingReportCompletionEvent
        extends ReportScheduleEvent {

    private final int eventsToExpect;
    // ...
}

public class ReportCompletionEvent extends ReportSchedulingEvent {
    // ...
}

public class YourListener
    implements ApplicationListener<ReportSchedulingEvent> {

    private final DatabaseWriter dbWriter;
    private volatile int expectedEvents = 0;

    public void onApplicationEvent(final ReportSchedulingEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof IncomingReportCompletionEvent) {
            this.expectedEvents = 
                    ((IncomingReportCompletionEvent) event)
                    .getExpectedEventCount();
        } else {
            this.expectedEvents--;
            if (this.expectedEvents == 0) {
                this.dbWriter.doYourThing();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created the event and listener which is good idea...Not sure what u mean by "Move to use a queue". What am I holding in queue...reportSchedules or tasks? Can you include sample to illustrate first two points...

Comment: @M06H See edits.  Obviously there are other ways to go like having a singleton listener that you can keep up to date, etc.

Comment: can you assume there is only one Listener `ReportScheduledProcessedListener` where `onApplicationEvent()` it checks the size and update your answer? Also, I don't really want to use this factory class and wondering how else the `ReportScheduledProcessedListener` can work out all events completed ?

Comment: @M06H: Given a rough outline of how something like that could work; ignoring thread-safety, etc.  I'm afraid you're going to have to fill in any more blanks yourself though.